# Masonite throw Invalid secret key error, even after secret key is created

Tags: pipenv, python-3.7, masonite

I'm trying to set sessions `request.session.set('request_token', oauth.request_token)` and it is throwing

> InvalidSecretKey > You have passed an invalid secret key of:
>   your-secret-key. Make sure you have correctly added your secret key.

I did `craft key --store` to create a secret key and store it.

Masonite `masonite==2.0.20` with `pipenv` for package mangement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply deactivated the virtual environment and enabling again solve the problem. 
Looks like `pipenv` cached the `.env` variables.

```
$ deactivate
$ pipenv shell
```